# Can we overload sprintf in g++ implementation?

Tags: c++, g++, printf

My friend was assigned to work on an existing C++ project of his company. In the source code he saw something like this:

```
char* tmp = "882.30";
char buff[32];
sprintf(buff, "%e", tmp);
printf("TEST: %s\n", buff);
```

When compiling, a warning was raised: `warning: format '%e' expects type 'double', but argument 3 has type 'char*'` but the output was amazing: `8.823000e+002`. He was curious. How could it be?

To clarify that he created a new small project and he used the same above code snippet and same compiler but it showed very different result: `2.647480e-314`.

The environment: Centos 5.x, gcc 4.4.7.

What could be the reason here? The existing project has overloading function of sprintf or compilers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's undefined behavior.

C99 §7.19.6.1/9

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

That means you are guaranteed to get unportable results/behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need `atof` to explicit convert from `char *` pointer to `double`

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main( void )
{
    const char* tmp = "882.30";
    char buff[32];
    sprintf(buff, "%e", atof( tmp )); 
    printf("TEST: %s\n", buff);
    return 0;
}
```

BTW, you can't override an existing function because that is violation to the
One Definition Rule (ODR.)

Comment: I know. You misunderstood why I asked this question.

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer. Which is environment of `8.823000e+002`? The environment: Centos 5.x, gcc 4.4.7.?

Comment: Yes. Centos 5.x, gcc 4.4.7